# IPython full suggestionlist

Tags: ipython

I want to see the full list of possible suggestions in IPython, not like in the image.

What command do you need to do that?

[image: Ipython Tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press tab twice, you can navigate around that list using the arrow keys.

You can also switch between three different styles of completer, by changing this setting in the file `ipython_qtconsole_config.py` in your profile directory (do `ipython locate profile` to see where that is):

```
# The type of completer to use. Valid values are:
# 
# 'plain'   : Show the available completion as a text list
#             Below the editing area.
# 'droplist': Show the completion in a drop down list navigable
#             by the arrow keys, and from which you can select
#             completion by pressing Return.
# 'ncurses' : Show the completion as a text list which is navigable by
#             `tab` and arrow keys.
c.IPythonWidget.gui_completion = 'ncurses'
```